# Why do people say linear SVM is a parametrized model and kernel SVM is not?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, parameterization

I am confused by what people mean when they say that linear SVM is a parametrized model and kernel SVM is not.

Aren't both methods trying to compute a decision boundary using some optimization program?

This decision boundary is a function $f$ which has some parameter attached to me, such as $w^T x + b$ or $\phi(w^T x + b)$.

I'm not quite seeing the reason why kernel SVM are not parametrized.

Comment: Following post provides a conscise answer i think: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481203/why-is-rbf-kernel-svm-a-non-parametric-algorithm#:~:text=It%20says%20that%20linear%20SVM,makes%20it%20non-parametric." Ps: sorry, I dont have option to comment original question somehow, hence responding as "answer"